# Linux: Deleted user with "-r" tag. And the whole directory got removed

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I deleted a user at my Debian 11 VPS. But I don't notice the "-r" tag. Now the whole parent directory got deleted. Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: if you talking about hdd hard drive, testdisk or extundelete (from pendrive)

Comment: I already tried both. in Testdisk the folder ist red marked. and extundelete don't works for me

Comment: yes red marked means deleted so you can undelete it